# the setting of @config(manifest="...") with Robolectric cannot found manifest, use eclipse in Win8 OS

Tags: android, eclipse, robolectric

I am trying to follow the Robolectric's eclipse quick start tutorials with Win8 OS that run robolectric unit test , but I am getting error as AndroidManifest.xml not found on path.

Can anyone give me an example path of @Config manifest value. Is it relative path or absolute one?

more information:

E:\Eclipse_workspace\TestProject\test\com.sample.robolectric.MainActivityTest.java
E:\android_workspace\sampleProject\app\src\com.sample.robolectric.MainActivity.java
E:\android_workspace\sampleProject\app\AndroidManifest.xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear guys，I has figure it out！

@Config(manifest = "../../sampleProject/app/AndroidManifest.xml")